# Upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 or fresh install 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I have installed Ubuntu server 14.04 which is running only `apache2` (for some static sites).
I would like to upgrade to 16.04 version but I don't know which way to proceed. Should I upgrade to 16.04 through terminal (using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts)) or install Ubuntu server 16.04 from scratch?

Comment: Make sure to back up all of your apache folders before doing anything.

Comment: I have already taken a backup from my folders, thanks for mentioning though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really only have an `apache` installed and some html files then I would recommend you copy the files somewhere else and do a fresh install. It will be faster and cleaner.